# Access(get) value in html file on ajax success return data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I got a json array in AJAX success response. Now I want to get that value in HTML file in PHP variable.

Comment: show some code ...

Comment: @bilal ahmed : Jquery-<script>$('#id').val(data.length);</script>
Php - $val = '<script>$('#id').val();</script>';

so here i will get $val as string, but i just want the value, for eg 5 (size of data)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try This Way.

```
 success:function(data)
      {

        $('#html_id').val(data.id);
        $('.html_class').val(data.class);
         $('.html_class').html(data.division);

      }
```

> **val** is use for input field and **html** use for plain text.

Comment: Thanks Gabrielle, I was also doing this, now i want to get $('#html_id').val(data.id) in php variable in html file, as m passing size of data and need to write a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP file array:**

`echo json_encode(array("var1" => $var1, "var2" => $var2));`

**jQuery file**

```
success: function(data){ 
     //var1 = data.var1;
     //var2 = data.var2;
     $('.yourhtmlclass').html(data.var1);
     $('#yourhtmlid').val(data.var2);
}
```